# Giving subjects a binary id they keep for every period

Tags: stata, identifier, dummy-variable, panel-data, economics

In Stata I have a list of subjects and contributions from an economic experiment.
There are multiple rounds being played for each treatment. Now I want to keep track of those who contributed in the first period and give them either 1 if a contributor or 0 if a defector. The game is played for multiple periods, but I only really care about the first round. My current code looks like this

```
    g firstroundcont = 0
    replace firstroundcont = 1 if c>0 & period==1
```

This however results in everyone getting a 0 for every subsequent period meaning that they are not "identified" as either a "first round" contributor or a defector for all other periods in the dataset. The table below shows a snippet of how my data looks and how the variable firstroundcont  *should* look.

| sessionID | period | subject | group | contribution | firstroundcont |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 10 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: I suggest you consult the Stata Wiki for asking a question on Stack: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info. Some use of `bysort` will likely work here, but without a reproducible example to illustrate how data is structured I cannot say for certain.

Comment: My bad. Im quite new to stackoverflow so am not really used to how things work, but thanks for the replies. And yes I noticed that right after I posted it @NickCox

Answer (score 0):

@JR96 is right: this sorely and surely needs a data example. But I guess you want something with the flavour of

```
 bysort id (period) : gen wanted = c[1] > 0
```

See https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-dummy-variables/ and https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099 for more on how to get indicators in one step. The business of generating with 0 and then replacing with 1 can usually be cut to a direct one-line statement.

Comment: Something like `egen firstroundcont = max(c>0 & period == 1), by(id)` would be apt if not every subject begins in period 1

Comment: Indeed; but if you look inside `egen.ado` and `_gmax.ado` you'll see that's dozens of lines of code doing it a slow way. (And yes, I often use `egen` in example code.)

Comment: Thank you JR and @NickCox. I'll check out the stuff you commented. I've added a data example to the original post (and fixed the definitely faulty code).

Comment: Replace `id` with `subject` and you should have your answer